# Cannot Declare Reference to tf2_msgs::TFMessage

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Background:**

I had a great callback function in a Gazebo plugin. I declared it with

void OnMsg(ConstVector3dPtr &msg)

and subscribed-to by my plugin's Load function with

subscriber = node->Subscribe("~/eb/vel_cmd", &MyPlugin::OnMsg, this);

**Problem:**

Instead of subscribing to "~/eb/vel_cmd", I'm subscribing to "/tf", so I need to change the message type of the callback (MyPlugin::OnMsg) to tf2_msgs::TFMessage. I followed the convention of the question in the link below to create a constant pointer for a tf2_msgs::TFMessage message.

http://answers.ros.org/question/21481...

Following the positionCb callback declaration in that code, now my callback is declared with:

private: void OnMsg(const tf2_msgs::TFMessage::ConstPtr& &msg)

I'm getting all kinds of compiling errors, but the biggest problem appears to be "Cannot declare reference to tf2_msgs::TFMessage_std::allocator<void >::ConstPtr& {aka class boost::shared_ptr<const tf2_msgs::tfmessage_std::allocator<void="">&}' (picture below).

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

**Compiling Errors:**
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14768/cannot-declare-reference-to-tf2_msgs::tfmessage/) by [ElizabethA](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2837/elizabetha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like you're trying to mix gazebo transport with ROS. A Gazebo subscriber is not able to subscribe to ROS messages and vice-versa. You'll need a ROS node for that.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/frc_red_team/src/3af1ba4bc832c06e282a825c50f9d2a51cf1a140/frcred_gazebo/src/joy_to_joints/JoyToJoints.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#JoyToJoints.cc-66)'s an example of a ROS subscriber in a Gazebo plugin.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ElizabethA](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2837/elizabetha/) on 2016-11-04**:
That was the problem!  Thanks so much for the example.

I also found this link to a Gazebo tutorial, once I knew what to look for, that also helped.
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i6

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-11-04**:
Nice find, I looked a bit for a tutorial which mentioned it and couldn't find one. Feel free to accept this answer so others know it solved your issue ;)